# Custom TopBar using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to develop a custom Topbar like below:

[image: Custom Topbar]

I have tried developing TopAppBar using jetpack compose but now wanted to have collapsed and expanded effect on Topbar and because of that, I wanted to develop a custom top bar. Please let me know if the above screenshot can be achieved from the below code.
Apologies as I am new to jetpack.

```
@Composable
fun TopNavBar(
    navController: NavController,
    title: String,
    showActions: Boolean = false,
    showAvatar: Boolean = true
) {
    val toolbarHeight = 52.dp
    val toolbarOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    TopAppBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(toolbarHeight)
            .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value.roundToInt()) },

        //  title = { Text("toolbar offset is ${toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value}") }
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
        title = {
            Text(
                text = title,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryLabel,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
            )
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_back),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.back),
                    tint = Grey8
                )
            }
        },
        actions = {
            // RowScope here, so these icons will be placed horizontally
            if (showActions) {
                IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_menu_search),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.search),
                        tint = Grey8
                    )
                }

                IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_create),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.create),
                        tint = Grey8
                    )
                }
            }
            if (showAvatar) {
                IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_avatar),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.profile),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(32.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: How should it behave? Does the title have to hide when scrolling up?

Comment: Please check this [https://material.io/archive/guidelines/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-behavior]and check for flexible space. Ideally when scrolling up the title will move to top next to drawer icon